# Why is Dr Dolittle not a vegetarian?

Tags: doctor-dolittle

I am reading [*The Voyages of Doctor Dolittle* (1922)](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1154) and there are several references to him eating bacon and other meats.

How is that Dr Dolittle is not a vegetarian?

> When I opened the front door I could smell bacon frying, so I made my way to the kitchen. There I discovered a large kettle boiling away over the fire and some bacon and eggs in a dish upon the hearth. It seemed to me that the bacon was getting all dried up with the heat. So I pulled the dish a little further away from the fire and went on through the house looking for the Doctor.

> The next morning when we were eating a very excellent breakfast of kidneys and bacon, prepared by our good cook Bumpo, the Doctor said to me,

I find it difficult to imagine conversing with animals, knowing they are intelligent and eating them.

I would expect a response more like Arthur's with [Douglas Adams's cow that wants to be eaten](http://remotestorage.blogspot.com/2010/07/douglas-adamss-cow-that-wants-to-be.html)

> "I just don't want to eat an animal that's standing there inviting me to," said Arthur, "It's heartless."

Speaking toward historical precedent, there was a [History of vegetarianism in Great Britain, that preceded the Dolittle books by decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_vegetarianism#Great_Britain)

I am aware of the [*Dr Dolittle* 1967 film soundtrack "Vegetarian"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Kwl6ImvR9I) but it is a work created 20 years after the death of the author, of the book quotes included here. This question is about the original work by [Hugh Lofting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Lofting).

Comment: Not all animals are vegetarian, why shouldn't he be like other carnivores?

Comment: @Paulie_D people are omnivores not carnivores.  Eating meat is a choice not a dietary requirement.

Comment: @terdon Animals are essentially people in the Dolittle books: intelligent, talking creatures, seen as friends not dumb beasts. If one of your friends is a pig, wouldn't it be weird that you also eat dead pigs? Excellent question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes, the point I am trying to make is that all this should be mentioned in the question so it can be put into context. Which James has now done, so I'm deleting my comments.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Kwl6ImvR9I

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I saw that, but it is a work created 20 years after the death of the author, in the book quotes I included. This question is about the original work by [Hugh Lofting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Lofting)

Comment: I was going to say that it simply would have been unusual and almost deviant for the time, but it looks there was a thousands-strong vegetarian movement at the time Dr. Dolittle is set.

Comment: There is that. :) But I couldn't resist adding it.

Comment: Hence the constant look of fear on Gub-Gub's face. https://img.fantasticfiction.com/images/n9/n47944.jpg

Comment: The bigger question is why Dolittle isn't a committed fruitarian, since vegetables also have a language in Lofting's series of books ***"“I found that his knowledge of insect languages, even down to the water-beetles, was tremendous – far and away better than my own. And from that he went on to learn the languages of the vegetable world.” “The language of vegetables!” cried Gub-Gub. “Well,” said the Doctor, “not exactly the languages of potatoes and carrots. We hadn’t any up there. I had often wondered, years ago, if our plants down here had any way of talking to one another"***

Comment: _["I weep for you," the Walrus said:
"I deeply sympathize."](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html)_.

Comment: Not trying to pass judgement, but many real-life animals *are* very intelligent, emotionally developed, and communicative - and many people are well aware of it.  And they eat them anyway. Sure, it's all slightly amped up in Dolittle's case, but I think if intelligence were a major issue, many of us would already eat far fewer animals. We tend to be fine with it because they aren't humans. My guess is, same goes for Dolittle.

Comment: Is the question asking how Dolittle can enjoy meat of an animal that he knows to be intelligent, or is it asking how he can just stand by and allow animals to be killed for food when he knows they are intelligent? Two slightly different questions there. If it's the first, there just might not be much of a conflict for the Doctor - they're dead anyway, might as well enjoy it (goes to that "would you eat human meat if it was voluntarily donated" hypothetical).

Comment: @DavidS The question is asking the former if you read the post body as it mentions him eating meat. However, an answer to the former probably answers the latter as well.

Comment: The question you're asking is not answerable.  We can't tell you why an author didn't have the protagonist be vegetarian because no cannon explanation was offered.

Comment: @JRodge01 It might be answerable if letters or interviews of Lofting were ever published in which he answered the question.

Comment: There's a lovely bit in that book where the Doctor plays brave matador to stop the cruelty of bullfighting -- after the earlier plot point where the Doctor's party is disturbed to find they are running low on salt beef!

Comment: @eac2222 presumably a swift kill in a slaughterhouse >> slow kill in a bullfight

Comment: @JacobC.saysReinstateMonica Even if Lofting explicitly said in an interview, it wouldn't be sufficient because it wouldn't be an in-universe explanation.  It'd be like J K Rowling giving more details after books have been published.

Comment: @JRodge You said "We can't tell you why an author didn't have the protagonist be vegetarian". Such a letter would answer at least *that* interpretation of the question as definitively as any in-work explanation. When there is no in-work answer to supercede it, "Word of God" makes sense to treat as an acceptable answer. Tolkien's letters have repeatedly been referred to here on points not explicitly addressed by his works.

Answer (score 3):

Reading a little farther in the book, about page 166 you find this discussion about Ben Butcher, able seaman {*unpleasant human stowaway*).

> “Yes, and think yourself lucky,” Polynesia put in, “that you are not locked up for stowing away and eating all our salt beef.”
>
> “I don’t know what the mischief we’re going to do now,” I heard her whisper to Bumpo. “We’ve no money to buy any more; and that salt beef was the most important part of the stores.”
>
> “Would it not be good political economy,” Bumpo whispered back, “if we salted the able seaman and ate him instead? I should judge that he would weigh more than a hundred and twenty pounds.”
>
> “How often must I tell you that we are not in Jolliginki,” snapped Polynesia. “Those things are not done on white men’s ships—Still,” she murmured after a moment’s thought, “it’s an awfully bright idea. I don’t suppose anybody saw him come on to the ship—Oh, but Heavens! we haven’t got enough salt. Besides, he’d be sure to taste of tobacco.” [Source](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1154/1154-h/1154-h.htm)

It would seem that by the morals of the group, it permissible to eat any meat, that is not your friend.

This of course is not an acceptable full answer to the question, but it does provide some insight towards answering the question.